# passing data to a php-script in a console

Tags: php, web

I want to pass data(strings/integers/arrays) from a php-script in a browser to a php-script in a console on the same server. Is there an easier way than than write it in a file and read it out?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want.

Comment: Easier is a comparative word. Easier than what??

Comment: console.log('<?php echo ($label)?>');

Answer (score 0):

3 ways you could go about this

1) **Database it**

This would be the standard way of doing what you are talking about, you would set a db table up as a key/value store with a timestamp (allowing you to query by time) and your web scripts saves data to the store and your cli script reads them and processes them.

This would be permanent and relatively fast.

2) **Cache it**

You could use a key/value cache to do it, something like memcache when a value gets passed to the web script it would store the value to memcache, you would save a timestamp to the data (so all values are stored as an array containing the value and a timestamp)

This would be a little more work to setup (installing memcache and standardising your value store) and has the disadvantage of not being permanent. For a large number of values and users it would be more efficient though.

3) **Use Both**

See the following link to take a look how memcahce can be setup with mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html